# Google maps remove default man icon

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i am using google maps with my project as you can see here ( [Demo](http://f.hybridsoftware.net/map.htm) )

in left top you can see man icon and zoom 
i want to remove man icon and set zoom left-top 
what should i do? i am using this library [js library](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false) and you can see other library in (view) source demo link [3] 
[image: this is my aim.look left top please]

Comment: Have you solved this issue ?

Answer (score 19):

This should remove the street view (the man) and the pan control:

```
var mapOptions = {
  center: mapCenter,
  zoom: 10,
  panControl: false,
  streetViewControl: false,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP      
};
```

Example of using Google Maps options:

```
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: i don't using map options. where should i add this?calling a event listener? this is my source :  view-source:http://f.hybridsoftware.net/map.htm

Comment: I can see from your code that you are doing things a little differently where you are performing map operation directly on the canvas node. Generally a 'map' variable is created and then bound to the canvas div as shown in the example I added to my response. It might be possible to apply the option directly to the canvas div but I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 3):

I hope you work

```
function initialize() {
   var mapOptions = {
   zoom: 8,
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
   disableDefaultUI: true,   //disables controls
   zoomControl: true,        //zoom control enables
   zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,  //enables the dimension
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT  //position enables
    },

   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);
  }
```

Comment: i don't using map options. where should i add this?calling a event listener? this is my source : view-source:f.hybridsoftware.net/map.htm

Answer (score 3):

to disable the man icon, you can set the streetViewControl into false in your map options.

```
streetViewControl: false
```

Answer (score 2):

The above answers do not meet your question. Try this caused its work for me to disable the people icon.

```
mapTypeControl:false,
scaleControl:false,
streetViewControl:false,
overviewMapControl:false,
rotateControl:false,
```

if you want to remove all then use this :

```
mapTypeControl: false,
disableDefaultUI: true,
```

if you want to style the map color, try this :

```
var mapStyles = [ {"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"administrative.land_parcel","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"visibility":"on"},{"lightness":10}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"lightness":50}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"hue":"#3b5998"},{"saturation":30},{"lightness":49}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"hue":"#3b5998"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"hue":"#3b5998"}]}, {featureType:'road.highway',elementType:'all',stylers:[{hue:'#3b5998'},{saturation:-92},{lightness:60},{visibility:'on'}]}, {featureType:'landscape.natural',elementType:'all',stylers:[{hue:'#3b5998'},{saturation:-71},{lightness:-18},{visibility:'on'}]},  {featureType:'poi',elementType:'all',stylers:[{hue:'#3b5998'},{saturation:-70},{lightness:20},{visibility:'on'}]} ];
```

change color attribute # as you like, then put this style in your map :

```
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
zoom: 9, // optional based on your requirement
styles: mapStyles
```

If you want to style the icons, then put this :

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
icon: "/images/icon/marker123.png", // based on your dir file
position: point, // based on your srcipt selection
map: map
```

Hope this useful for others. :)